# CSS Pseudo element jquery click event?

Tags: css, jquery, pseudo-element

I have an LI element "add folder" that uses a css pseudo before element to add a plus, like so:

[image]

the LI has a class of "add" and I have jquery that fires when "add" is clicked and CSS on the LI to show a cursor.

Of course, the pseudo element is not active.  I realize that pseudo elements are not part of the DOM, but how would you handle this sort of thing (preferably without resorting to an IMG tag) so the words AND the plus mark can be clicked?

Here is the CSS for the plus:

```
li.add:before {
    content: "\002B";
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background: $orangelight;
}
```

Comment: Just looking at that list item, the plus mark should be a child, not a sibling (which would solve your problem)... Perhaps refactor your markup?

Comment: The plus mark is not a sibling, it's assigned to the before pseudo element of the LI tag.

Comment: Is this a correct setup? http://jsfiddle.net/WhDY9/

Comment: @Steve: Then it should work as is (i.e. event should fire even when the plus sign is clicked). If it doesn't, something else is wrong.

Comment: @Ramunas You've created your fiddle just seconds faster :-)

Comment: @strah yeah, and they are almost identical... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works perfectly fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/Un4gq/

```
$("li").on("click", function () {
    alert("click");
})
```